# Scratch sprite won't stop movement

Tags: sprite, mit-scratch

I am making a Scratch Mit project where a sprite is supposed to come as a monster, I have controlled its custom movement using the repeat block although once it goes out of my desired animation, it replays the entire movement again including the part of the sprite I don't want to be displayed as of yet.

[code of the sprite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekBuy.png)

Moreover here is my project link, please look inside to see my errors and get more clarity on what my issue is:

https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/859974239/

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't with your monster sprite. Your project is full of messages sent between different sprites that makes your code very hard to read. Try to lay off all of the messages and create one sprite to control all of the others, and utilize variables to send messages as well. As your project gets larger, its going to become more difficult to keep yourself organized, so you need to start in this early stage. Once you've cleaned up all of the messages being sent in-between sprites, it should be pretty easy to find that a message looped back on itself and caused your monster animation to continue playing.